# WPF ProgressBar doesn't update?

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, progress-bar

I am trying to update my progressbar by using data bindings. The XAML file contains the progressbar:

```
<ProgressBar Height="23" Name="progressBar" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="207,444,0,0" Minimum="0" Maximum="{Binding ProgressBarMax}" Value="{Binding ProgressBarValue}" />
```

My relevant C# class contains the getter & setter:

```
    private int progressBarMax;
    public int ProgressBarMax
    {
        get 
        {
            if (this.progressBarMax == 0)
                this.progressBarMax = 1;
            return this.progressBarMax; 
        }
        set 
        {
            this.progressBarMax = value; 
        }
    }

    private int progressBarValue;
    public int ProgressBarValue
    {
        get 
        { 
            return progressBarValue; 
        }
        set 
        { 
            progressBarValue = value; 
        }
    }
```

In my "update" method the maximum is being set. For example like `this.progressBarMax = 100;`. In a loop the progressbar value is getting the value += 1. To see the updates I used Application.DoEvents(), later I will implement threads. The data binding has to be correct, because I have other components that work fine.

So why doesn't my progressbar update?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What does "Application.DoEvents()" do? Its not a standard WPF function.

Comment: I know. As I said, it will be replaced by threads soon, but for some tests it will show changes during my loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake in my code. Unfortunately I changed my private members, not the public properties. So when using `this.ProgressBarValue += 1;` instead of `this.progressBarValue += 1;` everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a way to let your ProgressBar be notified whenever ProgressBarValue changes. Have a look at the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface.

Comment: It is implemented, as I said in my text. The other components are beeing updated. I used MVVM, so my ViewModelBase extends INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: @Forlan07: Your property setter should then include a call to `OnPropertyChanged("ProgressBarValue")`

Comment: I already tried that, but nothing seems to happen... BTW., I didn't need to use that function for my listbox databindings and so on.

Comment: I think you are confusing things around.

Answer (score 1):

What about INotifyPropertyChanged to make your UI controls detect updated values?

//daniel

Answer (score 1):

I was hoping to actually add a comment to the original post, but I will have to settle for a question regarding the original entered through the answer text bax.  Can you post your code as a unit? That is, all the code you needed to add to complete the binding?  I am having trouble getting all the pieces together to do a data binding for my maximum and value for my progress bar and it may help quite a bit.